# Remove Restangular specific data from an object before PUT

Tags: angularjs, tastypie, restangular

I am using [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) on an Angular webapp that uses [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to talk to my Django-Tastypie backend instead of `$resource`. For auto-complete, I'm loading a list as `Restangular.all('technology').getList({'slug__startswith':q});`, which adds an element to my my model. I can then do a `PUT` on my model to save it.

The problem is, the elements in my model are pure, un-Restangulariezed objects (since they are fetched by Restangular.one), and when I add the tags this way, the elements added are Restangularized (with Restangular-specific methods and properties). This throws a 500 error, of course. Any way out?

I know I could add a custom response extractor, like this.

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response) {
  var newResponse = response;
  if (angular.isArray(response)) {
    angular.forEach(newResponse, function(value, key) {
      newResponse[key].originalElement = angular.copy(value);
    });
  } else {
    newResponse.originalElement = angular.copy(response);
  }

  return newResponse;
});
```

But I'm looking for the cleanest way to do it.

EDIT: More data.

How the `technology` object should look like:

```
{0: Object
category: "LNG"
created: "2014-07-17T18:17:19.350286"
description: ""
id: 5
modified: "2014-07-24T13:15:16.618184"
name: "Python"
resource_uri: "/api/v1/technology/python"
slug: "python"
verified: true}
```

How it looks like, after being Restangularized:

```
{addRestangularMethod: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
all: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
allUrl: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
category: "LNG"
clone: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
created: "2014-07-17T18:17:19.350286"
customDELETE: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
customGET: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
customGETLIST: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
customOperation: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
customPOST: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
customPUT: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
description: ""
doDELETE: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
doGET: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
doGETLIST: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
doPOST: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
doPUT: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
fromServer: true
get: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
getList: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
getParentList: function (){return g}
getRequestedUrl: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
getRestangularUrl: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
head: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
id: 5
modified: "2014-07-24T13:15:16.618184"
name: "Python"
one: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
oneUrl: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
options: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
parentResource: null
patch: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
plain: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
post: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
put: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
remove: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
reqParams: null
resource_uri: "/api/v1/technology/python"
restangularCollection: false
route: "technology"
save: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
several: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
slug: "python"
trace: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}
verified: true
withHttpConfig: function t(){if(r){var n=p(r);be.apply(n,arguments)}if(this instanceof t){var o=nt(e.prototype),n=e.apply(o,n||arguments);return wt(n)?n:o}return e.apply(u,n||arguments)}}
```

Comment: Can you attach an example with data contents.

Comment: @BartoszDabrowski Done. I'm sure I have to perform do .plain() on the object, but somehow I'm not able to figure out where, since ngTagsInput needs a promise, and I'm not able to modify the result before the promise gets resolved. I guess I need to write a new promise altogether wrapping this promise.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this method on the github to clean the object from Restangularized data and it's doing the job.

```
data = Restangular.stripRestangular(RestangularObjectToClean)
```

mgonto said he was planning to add a clean() method on this issue [#667](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/667)